# Expected error was thrown: RangeError: Invalid array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, try-catch, reduce

I have a simple factorial function:

```
function factorial(n){
  let array = Array(n).fill(0).map((e, i) => i + 1)
  if (array.length) return array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

But for some reason, this is throwing `Expected error was thrown: RangeError: Invalid array length` in [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/factorial/train/javascript).

I'm trying to account for the array length being 0 / undefined via the `if-else` block.

However, I'm still getting the error. I'm not sure how else to account for invalid-range, and frankly, do not understand what it's referring to.

I also tried to throw a 'rangeError' within a `try-catch`:

```
function factorial(n) {
  try {
    let array = Array(n)
      .fill(0)
      .map((e, i) => i + 1);
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof TypeError) {
      throw new error();
    } else if (error instanceof RangeError) {
      throw new error();
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

And in fact, this created a second error:
`TypeError: error is not a constructor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to throw [`RangeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError) there as specified in question for value below `0 or greater than 12`

```
function factorial(n) {
  if(n < 0 || n > 12){
    throw new RangeError('')
  }
  let array = Array(n).fill(0).map((e, i) => i + 1)
  if (array.length) return array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are given a negative number, you attempt to create an array of length < 0 which causes your error.  You need to handle negatives

```
Array(Math.abs(n))
```

This creates an array of the length regardless if it positive or negative.

Comment: Sorry but this creates an error for me `let array = Array(Math.abs(n).fill(0).map((e, i) => i + 1));` --> `TypeError: Math.abs(...).fill is not a function`

Comment: You missed a `)`.  `Array(Math.abs(n)).fill(0)`.  I also suggest looking at the other answers as they have the correct response for the codewars question you linked.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the question says that you need to throw RangeError when `n` is less than `0` and greater than `12`. So just use the `if` statement before that and you will pass.

```
function factorial(n){
  if(n < 0 || n > 12){
    throw RangeError;
  }
  let array = Array(n).fill(0).map((e, i) => i + 1)
  if (array.length) return array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
  else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```